# Use SQL Field in SSIS Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, expressionbuilder

Is it possible to reference a SQL field in your SSIS variable?

For instance, I would like use the field from the "table" below

```
Select '999999' AS Physician_Profile_ID
```

as a dynamic variable (named "CMSPhysProID" in our example) here

[image]

I plan on concatenating multiple IDs into a In statement.

Comment: Are you trying to use an expression to pass dynamic SQL command to a source? Or you need to store the value of a column within a variable?

Comment: I need to store the value of a column within a variable so it can be referenced in another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible by using execute sql task

#### In left side pan of Execute SQL task, general tab

1.Select result set as single row
2. Connection type ole db 
3. Set  connection and form SQL statement, As you mentioned *Select '999999' AS Physician_Profile_ID* 
 4.Go to result set in your left side pan 
5. Add your variable where you want to store '999999'
 6. Click ok

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to store the value within the variable to be used later, you can simply use an Execute SQL Task with a single row result set. More details in the following article:

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)

If you are looking to add a computed column while importing data, you must use a Derived Column Transformation within the data flow task to add a column based on another one, you can refer to the following article for more details about this component:

- [SSIS Derived Columns with Multiple Expressions vs Multiple Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-derived-columns-with-multiple-expressions-vs-multiple-transformations/)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish by concatenating the IDs into an "IN" statement? If the idea is to use the values of the IDs to limit the results, as a dynamic WHERE clause, you may have better luck just using a lookup against either a table you maintain with the desired IDs or even a static list generated in the package with a script task. (If you can use the lookup table method it will be much easier to maintain as you only have to update a table, not your source code.)

Alternatively, you may even be able to accomplish the goal with a join. Create a temp table from the profile IDs you want to keep and join to it, or, again, use it as a lookup component. Dynamically creating a where clause using IN will come in a lot slower and will be cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: I trying to create an URL string with a Where clause. For example, `"https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/resource/bqf5-h6wd.json?$where="+ 
@[User::PhysicianProfileIDs]     
+  "&$limit=100000"` The string is then used in Script Component Code